# Pandas Dataframe Advanced Split

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a big DataFrame I need to split into two (A and B), with the same number of rows from a certain column value in A and in B. That column has over 700 unique values, all of them strings. I leave an example:

```
DataFrame
  Price  Type
  1      X
  2      Y
  3      Y
  4      X
  5      X
  6      X
  7      Y
  8      Y
```

When splitting it (randomly), I should get two values of X, and two values of Y in DataFrame A and DataFrame B, like:

```
A
  Price  Type
  1      X
  5      X
  2      Y
  3      Y

B
  Price  Type
  4      X
  6      X
  7      Y
  8      Y
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How are the categories (`X`, `Y`, etc.) distributed?

Comment: Unevenly. There are more 2000 values of one, and 4 of others.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `groupby().cumcount()` to enumerate the rows within `Type`, then `%2` to divide rows into two groups:

```
df['groups'] = df.groupby('Type').cumcount()%2

A,B = df[df['groups']==0], df[df['groups']==1]
```

Output:

```
**A**

   Price Type  groups
0      1    X       0
1      2    Y       0
4      5    X       0
6      7    Y       0

**B**

   Price Type  groups
2      3    Y       1
3      4    X       1
5      6    X       1
7      8    Y       1
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Unfortunately it gives a 0 for the first item in every column, not a 0 for every item of a certain column value. Nonetheless it has given me an idea to continue and it has made things easier for sure!

Answer (score 1):

Could you group by the value of Type and assign A/B to half of the group as a new column, then copy only rows with the label A/B assigned? If you need an exact split you could base it off the size of the group

Comment: Could be a good idea, but I don't know how could I implement it.

Answer (score 0):

You can you use "arry_split" feature of numpy library like below:

```
import numpy as np
df_split = np.array_split(df, 2)
df1 = df_split[0]
df2 = df_split[1]
```

Comment: Sorry, doesn't work, it splits the data frame in two and the distribution is not symmetric

Comment: This code will split into two. If total number of records are even then distribution of two data frame will be equal. If total number of records are odd then first df will have one record more than second df. Because you can't distribute odd number of df into two df equally.